# .Net Chart Control label font always bold

Tags: .net, mschart, asp.net-charts

I am creating a chart-graphic with the .net char controls.
My problem is that the value-labels and the axis-labels are always bold if i dont use a white or transparent background!

```
.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = New Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.0F, FontStyle.Regular)
```

i set the font as regular, but it only appears as regular on my white background.
i am alternating backgrounds from white to gray. the font on the gray is always bold.

Any suggestions?

```
Dim myChart As New Chart
        With myChart
            .Width = 685 + 130
            .Height = 45 + letzteZusatz * 2
            .RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag
            .AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All
            .TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High
            If white Then
                .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 252, 252, 252)
                white = False
            Else
                .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 220, 220, 220)
                white = True
            End If
            .ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1")
            .ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle.Enable3D = False
            With .ChartAreas(0)
                .BackColor = Color.Transparent
                .BorderWidth = 0
                .AxisX.LineWidth = 0
                .AxisY.LineWidth = CType((0 + (letzteZusatz * 0.1)), Integer)
                .AxisY.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 194, 195, 192)
                .AxisY.Minimum = minimum
                .AxisY.Maximum = CType(maximum * 1.1, Integer)
                .AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = False
                .AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = True
                .AxisY.LabelStyle.Angle = 0
                .AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "N0"
                .AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = New Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.0F, FontStyle.Regular)
                .AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = False
                .AxisY.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.None
                .AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
                .AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = True
                .IsSameFontSizeForAllAxes = True
                .AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 194, 195, 192)
                .AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = True
                .AxisY.MinorTickMark.Enabled = False
                .AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = False
                .AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = False
                .AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 194, 195, 192)
                .BorderWidth = 0
                .AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Vertical
                .InnerPlotPosition = New ElementPosition(16, 0, 84, CType((100 - (letzteZusatz * 3)), Single))
            End With

            .DataBindTable(BuildChartTabel(o, seite), "Name")
For Each s As Series In myChart.Series
            s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar
            s.BorderWidth = 0
            s.MarkerSize = 0
            s.IsValueShownAsLabel = True
            s("PixelPointWidth") = "45"
            For Each p As DataPoint In s.Points
                p.BackImage = "~/img/bg_chart.png"
                p.BackImageWrapMode = ChartImageWrapMode.Tile
                p.BorderWidth = 0
                p.MarkerSize = 0
            Next
        Next
    End With

    Using chartimage = New FileStream("D:\test.png", FileMode.Create)
        myChart.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Png)
        chartimage.Flush()
    End Using
```

Comment: Does the background style have a property that sets the font to bold?

Comment: i am just setting: .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 220, 220, 220), cant find any other options for the background than setting color or image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with MS Chart, the label/legend text is always bold until I add the TextAntiAliasingQuality attribute:

*chart.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.Normal;*

Comment: It works, in my case TextAntiAliasingQuality.SystemDefault is a little better.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (where ChartAreas["A"] = your ChartAreas(0)):

```
chart1.ChartAreas["A"].BackColor = Color.Gray;
chart1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
//
chart1.ChartAreas["A"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(chart1.ChartAreas["A"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Font,
                                                                       FontStyle.Regular);
MessageBox.Show(chart1.ChartAreas["A"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Font.Bold.ToString());
```

**Also try changing your font to a font that has both a Regular and Bold appearance**

For instance:

```
System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
chart1.ChartAreas["A"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = f;
```

Comment: the bold property is false!

Comment: Have you tried changing the font to something else?
Perhaps the font you choose only has a bold-like appearance?
I think the default for charts is 'Sans Serif'.

Comment: tried different fonts! arial has no bold-like appearance because it is rendered as regular on white background!

Comment: @NikolajZander Please post more code so that we can try and replicate your situation. I am currently not able to reproduce your result. My chart works fine with Arial Bold and Arial Regular and with your Background color...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that AntiAliasing can affect fonts.

Try changing it to `AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.Graphics`.

Answer (score 0):

Pleasechange property of asp:chart TextAntiAliasingQuality to "Normal"

example:

```
<asp:Chart ID="ActionChart" runat="server" Height="154px" 
                Width="282px" TextAntiAliasingQuality="Normal">
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was looping through the Series Points after DataBind and setting the font there.

```
        Chart.DataBind();

        System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Helvetica", 15, FontStyle.Regular);

        foreach (var dp in Chart.Series["PieChartSeries"].Points)
        {
            dp.Font = f;
        }
```